# Where was R2-KT?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Prior to the release of *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*, it was reported that R2-KT, the droid created in honor of Katie Johnson, [would appear somewhere in the movie](http://comicbook.com/2015/11/29/r2-kt-is-appearing-in-star-wars-the-force-awakens/).

[image: R2-KT]

**Where did R2-KT appear in the movie?**

Comment: The girl's name is Katie Johnson, by the way. Her father is Albin Johnson. http://www.gktw.org/starwars/

Comment: Whoops, thanks. it was late and my brain started smashing names together.

Comment: @phantom42 : Please see updates to my answer below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## R2-KT appeared...

...in the last 10 to 12 minutes of the film, in the bottom right corner of the screen, at the resistance base...

> ...after the destruction of Starkiller Base but before Rey leaves to find Luke.

There may be another appearance, but this is the only one I managed to catch.

## Update : R2-KT appears 3 times (!)

Journalist Becki Hawkes of *The Telegraph* [enlisted the aide of the Twitterverse](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/film/star-wars-the-force-awakens/r2-kt-katie-johnson-501st-legion/) to catalogue all the instances of R2-KT in *The Force Awakens*.  Apparently, the droid appears 3 times:

> - Behind Poe Dameron’s ship during the scene in which he runs towards Finn (we were obviously too distracted by their joyful reunion to notice)
> - A second time, at the [Resistance] base, on the lower right hand side of the screen
> - At the [Resistance] base at the end of the film, when a injured fighter is being loaded on to a transporter

The third instance above is the one that I originally mentioned.

Comment: I looked for her too, and I also think I saw her in this scene: at the very end of the film, as the Falcon takes off, there's a cut to a shot of a crowd waving farewell. I think I saw R2-KT at the very right of this crowd, but the shot pans in and she is very quickly out of frame.

Comment: @Brian : Yes, that's the scene I'm referring to.  :-)