# Are R-series astromech units obsolete?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, technology, the-last-jedi, droids

Having watched TFA and TLJ a few times, I noticed that the only non-BB astromech droid we see is R2-D2, and he spends most of both of those movies in low-power mode and looking fairly worn out.

Are R-series astromech droids obsolete technology by the time of TFA? Is there any other explanation for why we see many R-series droids in the first six movies, but only BB units after that? As of TFA, R2-D2 is at least 65 years old (as he was fully operational in TPM, which was [65 years before TFA](http://www.digitalspy.com/movies/star-wars/feature/a825727/star-wars-timeline-chronology-phantom-menace-to-last-jedi/)), but that doesn't fully explain why there would not be more recently built R-units around, or why a 65-year-old droid would *necessarily* be considered obsolete.

Do we simply see no other R-series droid because they are truly considered obsolete tech that no one, Resistance, First Order, or other, would use unless they had no other choice (or were guided by sentimental reasons), or is this simply an artifact of the fact that the story is concentrated among small groups of people and places and the absence of an otherwise common R-unit is simply by random chance?

Comment: There are other R2 units as well in TFA, such as the pink one and the dark gray one...

Comment: @MrLister that sounds like an answer.

Comment: We see stacks of R2 units in the film and TV series...http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/R2_series_astromech_droid

Comment: @Valorum I'm talking specifically about the sequel series timeframe.

Comment: The dark gray one is R2-Q2, found to be present in TFA in this question: [Is this the same droid in two scenes from the Force Awakens?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/112545/4495), while the pink one, R2-KT, is the subject of this question: [Where was R2-KT?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/110987/4495)

Comment: So this one could be closed as a duplicate, but only because the premise isn't true. The question in the title could still be valid if you meant "are R2 units still being built by the time of TFA?" None of the other questions address that.

Comment: No, there are just more BB droids a-ROUND, haha hahhah.   <sigh>

Comment: @valorum and the spherical droids are harder to stack...

Comment: @Paul - That's why they [come in a box](https://h2savecom.files.wordpress.com/2017/12/bb-8-star-wars-mega-playset.png?w=777&h=538)

Comment: @Paul - Those BB units are very scary. That's why people sphere them.

Comment: Don’t stop now @Richard, you’re on a roll

Comment: I see you guys are having a ball.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are multiple [R-series](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/R-series) units in the foreground of this shot from The Force Awakens. It would appear that they're not obsolete, at least within the structure of the Resistance (which appears to be *somewhat* underfunded, but possesses some relatively new kit).

[image]

There are two other R-series droids seen in The Last Jedi. The Visual Dictionary has this to say on the subject

> RESISTANCE ASTROMECHS
>
> With its emphasis on starfighters and other small space transports,
>   the Resistance has a higher proportional need for astromechs than does
>   its First Order enemy. **Reliable R-series astromechs still see
>   extensive use, even though some models are nearing a century of
>   continuous operation.**

[image]